# Unable to provision my slick setup using traits, NullPointerException

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I rewrote my slick database layer to use traits (I was using classes before), and I am getting this error now:

It looks like my DatabaseConfig is null possible?

> Unexpected exception ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the
>   following errors:
>
> Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)   while
>   locating play.api.DefaultApplication   while locating
>   play.api.Application Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   play.api.db.slick.HasDatabaseConfig$class.driver(DatabaseConfigProvider.scala:142)

**Below is my controller that uses the dbService, along with the traits etc that I am using to wire up my slick code using play-slick (2.02)**

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject() (dbService: DbService) extends Controller {

}
```

Module:

```
bind(classOf[DbService]).to(classOf[DbServiceImpl])
```

My slick db layer is setup as follows:

```
trait DbService extends
  UserTable
  with AccountTable {

  this: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>
  import driver.api._

  // ..

  }

@Singleton
class DbServiceImpl @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
  extends DbService with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {

  import driver.api._



}


trait AccountTable {
  this: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>
  import driver.api._

  lazy val accounts = TableQuery[AccountsTable]

  def getAccountById(id: Int): Future[Option[Account]] =
    db.run(accounts.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)

  class AccountsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Account](tag, "accounts") {
      def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
      def companyName = column[String]("company_name")
        def * = (id, companyName) <> (Account.tupled, Account.unapply _)
  }
}
```

What seems to be the problem with my slick setup?  I can't figure it out so far.

**Update**

The full stack trace is here: https://pastebin.com/CXzUB0Kx

Comment: Can you show us DatabaseConfigProvider.scala line 142 and its context?

Comment: @Vitruvius it is from the library, maybe around here? https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DatabaseConfigProvider&type=

Comment: Have you got any mapped column type (not listed in the question)? Are all of them lazy loaded? Can you please post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @FedericoPellegatta I just made them all lazy, still no change.  Full stack trace is here: The full stack trace is here: https://pastebin.com/CXzUB0Kx

Comment: Could you please provide a small snippet of your `ApiService.scala` near line `80` and `Schema.scala` line `544`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash comes from here: https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/2.0.2/src/core/src/main/scala/play/api/db/slick/DatabaseConfigProvider.scala#L142, so you are right, your DatabaseConfig (`dbConfig`) is `null`.

This could be an initialization order problem. As you can see in the code referenced above, `driver` (being a `lazy val`) is certainly meant to be accessed after instanciation.

Did you post the full stacktrace? The full stacktrace leading to the `NullPointerException` would allow identifying where this access comes from.

Without a more precise stacktrace, you should ensure that you do not access `driver` or members imported through `import driver.api._` too early. The most likely cause would we some `val` that you should turn into `lazy val`.

**After stacktrace update**

It seems that one of you lazy field here `ApiService.scala:80` gets initialized, probably from the constructor of `WebsiteTable` here `Schema.scala:544`, called from `ApiService.scala:81`. Please review these locations or post the relevant code here if possible.